# Using clipboard with selenium and pyvirtualdisplay

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, clipboard, pyvirtualdisplay

I have a selenium script that works and must use a virtual disaply (pyvirtualdisplay or
xvfbwrapper) and at the end clicks a copy to clipboard button. the scripts works fine on windows (without a virtual display) but not on linux.
I belive the problem is that the libaries I tried to use the clipboard with (like pyperclip) use the OS clipboard with does not exist, how can I use the virtual display's clipboard?

my code starts like this:

```
display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()
pyperclip.determine_clipboard()
```

the problem occurs here:

```
    copy_btn = WebDriverWait(driver,100000).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'button[title="Copy Full Text"]')))
    copy_btn.click()
    print('Text Copied')
    time.sleep(2)
    clip = pyperclip.paste()
```

The Error message:

pyperclip.PyperclipException:
Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
For more information, please visit https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#not-implemented-error

Comment: did you find a solution ? this did not happen before, but it happens now, not sure why

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas and it will work on Windows and Linux

```
import pandas as pd
myvariable = pd.read_clipboard()
print(myvariable)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my little workaround:

```
def paste_to_element(driver, element, text):
    # Create a temporary HTML file with the text content
    temp_file_path = 'temp.html'
    with open(temp_file_path, 'w') as temp_file:
        temp_file.write("<body>"+text.replace("\n","<br>")+"</body>")
    # Open the temporary HTML file in a new tab
    driver.execute_script("window.open('about:blank', '_blank');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    driver.get('file://' + os.path.abspath(temp_file_path))
    # Wait for the webpage to load
    time.sleep(3)
    # Copy the text from the webpage
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'a')
    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"body").send_keys(Keys.CONTROL, 'c')
    # Close the tab
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    # Delete the temporary file
    os.remove(temp_file_path)
    # Paste the copied text into the element
    element.send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + Keys.INSERT)
```